# Mustache Render Ignoring all {{ }}

Tags: jquery, mustache

I'm using the following basic introduction example from here:
https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

I'm using the following code:

```
  var tmp_view = {
    title: "Joe",
    calc: function(){
      return 2+5;
    }   };

  var tmp_output = Mustache.render("{{title}} spends {{calc}}", tmp_view);
```

However, in my browser all I'm getting is:

```
var tmp_output = Mustache.render(" spends ", tmp_view);
```

Which renders "spends"

Edit:  I think I have a better understanding of why this is happening but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I am using spark for my server and have the following

```
get("/foobar", (req, res) -> new ModelAndView("",
        "foobar.mustache"), new MustacheTemplateEngine());
```

In my .mustache file I make a JSON request and inside that JSON request is where I want to render another template.

Comment: Can you post your full code? Maybe in a fiddle? What you posted is working for me.

Comment: How are you loading it in the browser? I see this happen when I've got both a server side templating language _and_ a client side templating language that use similar interpolation mechanisms. So for instance, I'm trying to render something with angular.js, which uses `{{ }}` but I'm in a server-side template that uses Hogan.js (which _also_ uses `{{ }}`) so hogan sees that the value is undefined and renders it as an empty string leaving nothing for angular to do.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7yp3yn7z/1/

Comment: To add to @tandrewnichols comment, laravel's blade templating also uses `{{ }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to [redefine your delimiter](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#set-delimiter) in mustache.

Based on mustache documentation :

> Set Delimiter tags start with an equals sign and change the tag delimiters from {{ and }} to custom strings.
>
> Consider the following contrived example:
>
> - {{ default_tags }}
>     {{=<% %>=}}
> - <% erb_style_tags %>
>     <%={{ }}=%>
> - {{ default_tags_again }}
>     Here we have a list with three items. The first item uses the default tag style, the second uses ERB style as defined by the Set Delimiter tag, and the third returns to the default style after yet another Set Delimiter declaration.

Call `{{=<% %>=}}`to change `{{ }}`by `<% %>`